# Can rehashing be avoided in hashmap?

Tags: java, hash, hashmap

My friend was asking me about an interview question today.

Is there a way to prevent /avoid Hashmap? The interviewer gave a clue that there is a hook by which rehashing can be avoided

I tried looking into the HashMap code and looks like as soon as it hits the load factor it rehashes

Setting the load factor to a higher value can only delay the rehashing process

Am confused if at all its possible to prevent rehashing

If someone can point me in the right direction it can help

Comment: Make the initial capacity bigger than the maximum number of items that will be stored divided by the load factor?

Comment: Yes, by tuning the load factor. And yes, it is only possible to avoid completely if you know how many elements will be added.

Comment: Sigh ... another interviewer who wants to test whether prospects have memorized the source of the Java runtime...  I just don't see what the point of asking questions like this is.

Comment: How about specifying infinity as the load factor?

Comment: I also don't see the point of questions about how to improve hashmap performance. It is *O(1)* within very broad limits, and rehashing isn't such a burden that it is worthy of an interview question. The company should already have its own hotshot programmers hardwired in from startup if it's really interested in this kind of thing, which in 99 cases out of 100 it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it can be avoided if you know the size of your hashmap beforehand.

Set `loadFactor` = 1 (default value is 0.75)

`initialCapacity` = `size of hashmap + 1` (default value is 16).

Use the following constructor to instantiate your hashmap

```
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
```

This will work because in the below code snippet from the HashMap class, the condition `(size >= threshold)` will never be satisfied, so the hashtable is never resized.

```
void addEntry(int paramInt1, K paramK, V paramV, int paramInt2)
{
    if ((size >= threshold) && (null != table[paramInt2]))
    {
        resize(2 * table.length);
        paramInt1 = null != paramK ? hash(paramK) : 0;
        paramInt2 = indexFor(paramInt1, table.length);
    }
    createEntry(paramInt1, paramK, paramV, paramInt2);
}
```

Comment: what is  (size >= threshold) ?